# CasperJS fetchText() function echoing blank output

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to use `fetchText()` to print out the URL of a google search result to the terminal. Here's the image of what exactly I'm trying to print.

It's only prints out blank though! I don't see anything I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Code:

```js
phantom.casperPath = "/usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1.0.3/libexec/";

phantom.injectJs(phantom.casperPath + '/bootstrap.js');

var utils = require('utils');
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('https://www.google.com/search?q=amazon+shoes');

casper.wait(3000, function () {
    this.echo(this.fetchText('#rso > div:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(1) > div > div > div > div.f.kv._TD > cite'));
}).run();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google will change the page depending on the useragent string. So you need to set a string during creation (with example string)

```js
var casper = require("casper").create({
    pageSettings: {
        userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36"
    }
});
```

or with specific function

```js
casper.userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36");
```

Sometimes it is also necessary to set the [`viewport`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#viewport) to something desktop-like, because PhantomJS' default viewport is 400x300 and Google might render a different site based on the viewport.

Comment: Thanks. I actually found this out as well and was about to post! You get the gold.

One question: if I have the viewport, does it open up a window? I tried to add it, but it didn't work. The manual doesn't specify...

Comment: No, anything you set, is behind the scenes (headless) since PhantomJS is headless and there is no way to see what is going on. You can try the `--engine=slimerjs` to run in a semi-headless mode using http://slimerjs.org/ with your installed firefox.